# How can I prevent my Ajax/Json function to load slower and slower?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

index.php:

```
    <div class="start">START</div>
    <div class="content"></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

update1.php:

```
     <div class="fire">FIRE<div>
     <div class="result"></div>
```

update2.php:

```
$json = array(
        'unique' => uniqid(),
    );
echo json_encode($json);
```

script.js:

```
$(document).off("click", ".start").on("click", ".start", function (event) {

             $.ajax({
                url: "update1.php",
                data: {},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".content").html(data);
                }
            })
});


$(document).off("click", ".fire").on("click", ".fire", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "update2.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            encode: true,
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                $(".result").html(data.unique);
            }
        });
    });
```

I load some data via Ajax and after that I load a Unique ID with json encode. It is working well. The only problem is, that on every click "FIRE" the loading of the Unique ID is getting slower and slower.

The loading time is more or less like this

- Click "FIRE" ---> Loading time of Unique ID: 0sek
- Click "FIRE" ---> Loading time of Unique ID: 2sek
- Click "FIRE" ---> Loading time of Unique ID: 4sek
- Click "FIRE" ---> Loading time of Unique ID: really long that the mouse waiting symbol is turning and turning.

...

I cannot find out, why this is happening.

Comment: have you looked at the network tab in your dev tools to see if there is anything obvious? can you screenshot it (after you've run this a number of times) and share it on here?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I do not have any errors in the Dev tools. The only issue I can find is that one number is increasing on every click. I posted an image for you in the question

Comment: I didn't say errors, I said to post a screenshot of the network tab when you've fired this a few times

Comment: i setup this code in my pc i can't found any loading issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the PHP implementation of `uniqid()`

To avoid time-based collisions it will sleep for a given number of mircoseconds.

This can be mitigated against without losing the uniqueness that would occur in instances of time-based collision.

See detailed explaination here: [Why is uniqid slow?](http://blog.kevingomez.fr/til/2015/07/26/why-is-uniqid-slow/)

The key part of the solution is to set `more_entropy` to true to avoid time-based collisions.

> By setting more_entropy to true, we choose to provide an additional source of entropy by appending data using php_combined_lcg() (a pseudo-random number generator), thus preventing time-induced collisions without having to sleep.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with uniqid(). I I load just `echo "hello";` it is the same issue